# About metacompactness in Kelley's book

Tags: general-topology

I am studying Kelley's book on General Topology. On page 171, he proposes the following exercises.

> Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a point finite open cover of a normal space $X$. Then it
> is possible to select an open set $G(U)$ for each $U$ in $\mathcal{U}$ in such a way
> that $\overline{G(U)} \subset U$ and the family of all sets $G(U)$ is a cover of $X$.

The author suggests to follow this hint: consider the class of all functions $F$ such that: the domain of $F$ is a subfamily of $\mathcal{U}$, $F(U)$ is an open set whose closure is contained in $U$ for each $U$ in the domain of $F$, and $$\bigcup \lbrace F(U) \mid U \in \operatorname{domain} F \rbrace \cup \bigcup \lbrace V \mid V \in \mathcal{U}, \; V \notin \operatorname{domain} F \rbrace = X.$$ Then select a maximal member of this class.

Now, since $X$ is a normal space, given a member $U$ of $\mathcal{U}$, there exists an open set $V$ such that $\overline{V} \subset U$. Hence the class of functions is non-empty. I guess I should use some equivalent of the Axiom of Choice to construct a maximal member. I tried with Zorn's Lemma, but I am stuck. Given a chain in the class of functions, an upper bound is naturally defined by union, i.e. by extending functions to the union of all domains. This is reminiscent of the proof of the Hahn-Banach Theorem. But I cannot prove that the domain of the maximal element is $\mathcal{U}$. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, since $X$ is a normal space, given a member $U$ of $\mathcal{U}$,
> there exists an open set $V$ such that $\bar{V}\subset U$. Hence the
> class of functions is non-empty.

We have to be more careful. Say we put $F(U)=V\subseteq\bar{V}\subseteq U$. By definition of $\mathscr{F}$, we must choose $V$ such that $V$ and other members of $\mathcal{U}$ still covers $X$.

Let $A$ be the union of all $U'\in\mathcal{U}$ that is not $U$. The set $B=X-A$ is a nonempty closed subset of $U$. Choose open $V$ such that $B\subseteq V\subseteq\bar{V}\subseteq U$, and put $F(U)=V$. Then we are done.

Similarly, we have to be careful when applying Zorn's lemma.

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the collection of all such functions. Order $\mathscr{F}$ such that $F_1\leq F_2$ iff $F_2$ extends $F_1$. Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a chain in $\mathscr{F}$. Let $F$ be as the OP says. We need to verify that $F$ is indeed a member of $\mathscr{F}$. This is where point-finiteness comes into play.

Suppose, for contradiction, that $X$ is not covered by all $F(U)$ and all $V\notin\mathrm{dom}F$. Pick $x\in X$, such that $x$ is not in any $F(U)$ or $V\notin\mathrm{dom}F$. Then $x$ must be in some $U\in\mathrm{dom}F$. **By point-finiteness**, $x$ belongs to only finitely many $U_1,\dots,U_n\in\mathcal{U}$. None of these equals to any $V\notin\mathrm{dom}F$, so $U_1,\dots,U_n\in\mathrm{dom}F$. Each $U_i$ must be in the domain of some $F_i\in\mathscr{C}$. There are finitely many such $F_i$, so we can pick the maximum of them, say $F_1$. The point $x$ is not in any of $F_1(U_1),\dots,F_1(U_n)$, not in any other $U\in\mathrm{dom}F$, and not in any $V\notin\mathrm{dom}F$. Hence it is not in the set
\begin{align}
\bigcup\{F_1(U): U\in\mathrm{dom}F_1\}\cup\bigcup\{V:V\notin\mathrm{dom}F_1\},
\end{align}
impossible. We conclude that $F$ is indeed a member of $\mathscr{F}$, hence an upper bound of $\mathscr{C}$.

Now let $G$ be a maximal member of $\mathscr{F}$. Put $\mathcal{G}=\mathrm{dom}(G)$. By definition of $\mathscr{F}$, any $x\notin\bigcup\{G(U):U\in\mathcal{G}\}$ is a member of some $V\in\mathcal{U}-\mathcal{G}$. That is, $\mathcal{U}-\mathcal{G}$ is an open cover of
\begin{align}
Y=X-\bigcup\{G(U):U\in\mathcal{G}\}.
\end{align}
The subspace $Y$, as a closed subspace of the normal space $X$, is also normal. If $\mathcal{U}-\mathcal{G}$ is nonempty, then we can find $V_0\in\mathcal{U}-\mathcal{G}$ and open $W\subseteq\bar{W}\subseteq V_0$, such that $Y$ is covered by $W$ and all $V\in\mathcal{U}-\mathcal{G}-\{V_0\}$. This is done exactly the same way as how we proved $\mathscr{F}$ to be nonempty. By setting $G(V_0)=W$, we can extend $G$ and obtain a greater member of $\mathscr{F}$. This contradicts the maximality of $G$ in $\mathscr{F}$. We conclude that $\mathcal{U}=\mathcal{G}$, and the proof is complete.

---

As far as I can remember, Kelley does not use ordinals that much in his book. But if the OP knows about ordinals and transfinite recursion, then the proof can be written more intuitively. If not, just consider the case of countable $\mathcal{U}$, and regard $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha<\theta}$ as a countable sequence. The only difference is that ordinals count all sets (assuming choice), whereas natural numbers count only countable sets.

Enumerate $\mathcal{U}$ by a $\theta$-sequence $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha<\theta}$ for some ordinal $\theta$. Pick open $V_0\subseteq U_0$ such that $\bar{V}_0\subseteq U_0$, and $X$ is covered by $\{V_0\}\cup\{U_\alpha\}_{0<\alpha<\theta}$. This is possible because $X-\bigcup_{0<\alpha<\theta}U_\alpha$ is a closed set contained in $U_0$.

Continue the process: If an ordinal $\beta$ is such that $V_{\alpha}$ are defined for all $\alpha<\beta$, and such that $X$ is covered by $\{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\beta}\cup\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\geq\beta}$, then pick open $V_\beta\subseteq\bar{V}_\beta\subseteq U_\beta$ such that
\begin{align}
\{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\beta}\cup\{V_\beta\}\cup\{U_\alpha\}_{\beta<\alpha<\theta}
\end{align}
covers $X$. This way we recursively define a $\theta$-sequnce of open sets $(V_\alpha)_{\alpha<\theta}$.

We show that $\{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\theta}$ covers $X$. By point-finiteness, each $x\in X$ belongs to only finitely many $U_{\alpha_1},\dots,U_{\alpha_n}$. Put $\beta=\max\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$. Then $x\notin U_\alpha$ for all $\alpha>\beta$, so $x\in V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha<\beta$.